# Create sequence by condition in the case when condition changes

Tags: r, tidyverse

the data looks like:

```
df <- data.frame("Grp"=c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10)),
             "Year"=c(seq(2001,2010,1),seq(2001,2010,1)),
             "Treat"=c(as.character(c(0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1)),
                                   as.character(c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0))))
df
   Grp Year Treat
1    A 2001     0
2    A 2002     0
3    A 2003     1
4    A 2004     1
5    A 2005     1
6    A 2006     1
7    A 2007     0
8    A 2008     0
9    A 2009     1
10   A 2010     1
11   B 2001     1
12   B 2002     1
13   B 2003     1
14   B 2004     0
15   B 2005     0
16   B 2006     0
17   B 2007     1
18   B 2008     1
19   B 2009     1
20   B 2010     0
```

All I want is to generate another col `seq` to count the sequence of `Treat` by `Grp`, maintaining the sequence of `Year`. I think the hard part is that when `Treat` turns to 0, `seq` should be 0 or whatever, and the sequence of `Treat` should be re-counted when it turns back to non-zero again. An example of the final dataframe looks like below:

```
   Grp Year Treat seq
1    A 2001     0   0
2    A 2002     0   0
3    A 2003     1   1
4    A 2004     1   2
5    A 2005     1   3
6    A 2006     1   4
7    A 2007     0   0
8    A 2008     0   0
9    A 2009     1   1
10   A 2010     1   2
11   B 2001     1   1
12   B 2002     1   2
13   B 2003     1   3
14   B 2004     0   0
15   B 2005     0   0
16   B 2006     0   0
17   B 2007     1   1
18   B 2008     1   2
19   B 2009     1   3
20   B 2010     0   0
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `data.table` `rleid` , you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Grp, grp = data.table::rleid(Treat)) %>%
  mutate(seq = row_number() * as.integer(Treat)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)

#   Grp    Year Treat   seq
#   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <int>
# 1 A      2001 0         0
# 2 A      2002 0         0
# 3 A      2003 1         1
# 4 A      2004 1         2
# 5 A      2005 1         3
# 6 A      2006 1         4
# 7 A      2007 0         0
# 8 A      2008 0         0
# 9 A      2009 1         1
#10 A      2010 1         2
#11 B      2001 1         1
#12 B      2002 1         2
#13 B      2003 1         3
#14 B      2004 0         0
#15 B      2005 0         0
#16 B      2006 0         0
#17 B      2007 1         1
#18 B      2008 1         2
#19 B      2009 1         3
#20 B      2010 0         0
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Never used `rleid` before. Many thanks! I will wait a little bit for some other answers before I will accept yours.